# When to use a blank cin.get()?

Tags: c++

As the title says - when should I use a blank cin.get() ?

I encountered situations when the program acted strange until I added a few blank cin.get()s between reading lines. (e.g. in a struct when reading its fields I had to enter a cin.get() between each non-blank cin.get())

So what does a blank cin.get() do and when should I use it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are two broad categories of stream input operations: formatted and unformatted. Formatted operations expect input in a particular form; they start out by skipping whitespace, then looking for text that matches what they expect. They typically are written as **extractors**; that's the `>>` that you see so often:

```
int i;
std::cin >> i; // formatted input operation
```

Here, the extractor is looking for digits, and will translate the digits that it sees into an integer value. When it sees something that isn't a digit it stops looking.

Unformatted input operations just do something, without regard to any rules about what the input should look like. `basic_istream::get()` is one of those: it simply reads a character or a sequence of characters. If you ask it to read a sequence it doesn't care what's in that sequence, except that the form that takes a delimiter looks for that delimiter. Other than that, it just copies text.

When you **mix** formatted and unformatted operations they fight with each other.

```
int i;
std::cin >> i;
```

If `std::cin` is reading from the console (that is, you haven't redirected it at the command line), you'll typically type in some digits followed by the "Enter" key. The extractor reads the digits, and when it hits the newline character (that's what the "Enter" key looks like on input) it stops reading, and leaves the newline character alone. That's fine, if the next operation on that stream is also a formatted extractor: it skips the newline character and any other whitespace until it hits something that isn't whitespace, and then it starts translating the text into the appropriate value.

There's a problem, though, if you use a formatted operation followed by an unformatted operation. This is a common problem when folks mix extractors (`>>`) with `getline()`: the extractor reads up to the newline, and the call to `getline()` reads the newline character, says "Hey, I've got an empty line", and returns an empty string.

Same thing for the version of `basic_istream::get()` that reads a sequence of characters: when it hits the delimiter (newline if you haven't specified something else) it stops reading. If that newline was a leftover from an immediately preceding formatted extractor, it's probably not what you're looking for.

One (**really really ugly**) solution is the brute force `cin.ignore(256, '\n');`, which ignores up to 256 sequential newline characters.

A more delicate solution is to not create the problem in the first place. If you need to read lines, read lines. If you need to read lines and sometimes extract values from the text in a line, read the line, then create a `std::stringstream` object and extract from that.